# How to setup a dedicated Call of Duty Black Ops Server?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops, server-administration

I'm very late to the game (literally) and just now getting into [Call of Duty Black Ops](http://store.steampowered.com/app/42700/Call_of_Duty_Black_Ops/) multiplayer. I'd like to be able to setup a dedicated game server am looking for the basic steps to install, and configure the server.

I've found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubMiZqaDJho) that shows someone starting a server from a batch file, but I don't have this file in my installation. I used Steam to download the multiplayer version of the game.

Assuming I have a server class machine with Windows 2012 installed ready to go, what steps do I need to take to install and securely configure a Call of Duty Black Ops server?

Comment: Which CoD game? Some CoD games allow it and some don't.

Comment: Call of Duty: Black Ops http://store.steampowered.com/app/42700/Call_of_Duty_Black_Ops/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to run your own CoD BO server it is required to have it hosted by a specific server provider ([source](http://www.ign.com/articles/2010/09/10/black-ops-dedicated-servers-come-with-a-catch)). The only allowed way is to order a server at [GameServers.com](https://www.gameservers.com/blackops/), which will be set up for you on their end.

Since it is not allowed to run it from your own machine the plain answer is: **No way**. There is no way to do it legally.

Comment: For reference, here's the [**Black Ops Page**](https://www.gameservers.com/blackops/) on GameServers.com - the official hosting provider.